Draw foreach with CFG (Control Flow Grap)
Hello everyone in the community, does anyone know about CFG (Control Flow Graph)? Can you please tell me how to represent the DFG for a foreach loop?
This is a sample code:
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo $value;
}


There's no difference to ordinary loops - foreach just has an implicit index/loop counter.

How can we represent that implicit counter/loop on the CFG/DFG?
